# ClassPathXmlApplicationContext function file not found exception

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I'am working with spring hibernate maven project. Here i got exception `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file not found. How should i add the path . OR should i add classpath entry in .classpath file? 
my file is inside web-inf .
I have tried `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml");`

```
ApplicationContext appContext =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("dispatcher-servlet.xml");
```

Please help

Comment: Is this a web application? Why are you creating an `ApplicationContext` yourself?

Comment: keep it in the resources folder

Comment: yeah web application, application context.xml file is there for configure hibernate and other stuff

Comment: @m.sharma so i cant keep this file in web-inf ?

Comment: Show us where you are doing this. Do you have access to the `ServletContext`?

Comment: as you are using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext it expects that it is in classpath which is resources for maven

Comment: The `/WEB-INF` directory within your web application archive is not typically added to the web application's classpath by a Servlet container. As such, you won't be able to retrieve it with a `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` expects that the resource file is in classpath which is `resources` for maven.So try placing  `dispatcher-servlet.xml` in the resources folder of your maven project.

Comment: First part, correct, second part -- extremely bad practice, won't even work, forget it.

Comment: @Engineer Dollery Ya u are write updated it it will work now but not sure of performance issue

Comment: Still won't work. You can't access the source directory for the project from the deployed war. Not possible. Can't ever work. The source isn't available when the war is deployed. Nor should a war ever be accessing the filesystem.

Comment: ok in that case it wont work I agree but if you are running it on the IDE it definately going to work

Comment: I used `BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring.xml"));` it worked fine for me in intellij